# Showing that a meromorphic function has a dense range in a punctured disk with a non-isolated singularity

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity, meromorphic-functions

Suppose that $f$ is a meromorphic function on the punctured disk $0<|z|<1$ having poles on the set $\left\{\frac{1}{k}: k\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$. I would like to show that for every $1>r>0$, the restriction of $f$ to $0<|z|<r$ has a range that is dense in $\mathbb{C}$.

I know that if $f$ had an essential singularity at the origin instead of this dense set of poles, then [the Casorati–Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casorati%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) would guarantee that the range of $f$ is dense in any punctured disk.

How to deal with this dense set of zero though?

Comment: Same proof as casorati - assume range not dense so there is a small ball with center $w$ not in the range; then $g=1/(f-w)$ is holomorphic and bounded on the punctured disc in cause so extends holomorphically at zero, but $1/k$ are zeroes of $g$ which accumulate at $0$ etc